# html2canvas not captuare openstreet map and svg tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html2canvas

I'd like to implement capture screenshot for open-street map .

for this i am using html2canvas, it will capture current screen but not map and svg polygon,

for that i used AJAX cal like this:

```
function capture() {

  html2canvas($('.map-layout'), {
    logging: true,
    profile: true,
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {

      var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      $.ajax({
        url: "/take_screenshot",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({project_id:<%= @project.id%>, screen_url:dataUrl }),
        success:function(data){

          alert(data);

    }
  });
}
```

});
  }

In Controller, getting parameter and just save this image :

```
a = params[:screen_url]
data = a.split(",")[1]

File.open('map.png', 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(Base64.decode64(data))
end
```

it give these logs :

```
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 16 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 2 / 17 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 3 / 18 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 4 / 21 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 5 / 22 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 6 / 23 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 7 / 24 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 8 / 25 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 9 / 26 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 10 / 27 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 11 / 28 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 12 / 29 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 13 / 30 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 14 / 31 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 15 / 32 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 16 / 33 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 17 / 34 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 18 / 35 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 19 / 36 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 20 / 37 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: start: images: 21 / 38 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images html2canvas.js?body=1:20
html2canvas: Preload: Done. html2canvas.js?body=1:20
```

I want to capture screenshot of current screen, in this screen i use open street map and several tools like (zoom in, zoom out, export, bookmark, screen capture ).

so when i try above code it will generate screen shot but in this screenshot it will not capture map and polygon.

so my question is, How can i capture this map and polygon both in generated image.

so any idea why not capture map as well as svg?

Comment: What have you tried, what code are you using? What does your markup look like?

Comment: i just update my question, if you have any idea please share it will help me lot. i already tried with Webshot, IMGKit, Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, GrabzIt. but it will not fulfill my requaronments.